# Sort table when clicking the table head

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I'm trying to make a sortable user table that can be sorted by all the table heads. I have been able to get it to sort ascending and descending, but only by the name column. I'm new to reactjs and have not been able to implement it in my code.

here is the table component:

```
import { formatDate } from "../../utils/formatDate";
import "./table.css";

function Table(props) {
  const { headerData, bodyData, removeItem, sortData, ordIcon} = props;

  
  return (
    <div className="user-data">
      <table className="user-table">
        <thead>
          <tr className="data-th">
            {headerData.map((headerTable) => (
              <th onClick={sortData} id={"header-"+headerTable.toLowerCase()}>
                {headerTable} <img src={ordIcon} id="arrow-img"></img>
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {bodyData.map((item) => (
            <tr className="data-tr">
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.email}</td>
              <td>{item.occupation}</td>
              <td>{formatDate(item.birthday)}</td>               
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

and here is the sorting code in the Home:

```
const sortData = () => {
    
    if (order === "" || "asc") {
      let sortUserName = [...newUserArr].sort((a, b) =>
        a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
      );
      setOrder("dsc");
      setNewUserArr(sortUserName);
      setOrdIcon(arrowDown)
    } if (order === "dsc") {
      let sortUserName = [...newUserArr].sort((a, b) =>
        b.name.localeCompare(a.name)
      );
      setOrder("asc");
      setNewUserArr(sortUserName);
      setOrdIcon(arrowUp)
    }
  };
```

Thank you

edit:
headerData={headerUser}

`const headerUser = ["Name", "Email", "Occupation", "Birthday"];`

Comment: Can you please add the contents of ````headerData```` to the question?

Comment: Sure, just added it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one generic approach,

In `Home` component, add a variable storing the key and type of every column

```js
    const columnMap = {
        Name: {key: 'name', type: 'string'},
        Email: {key: 'email', type: 'string'},
        Occupation: {key: 'occupation', type: 'string'},
        Birthday: {key: 'birthday', type: 'date'}
    };
```

And then in the `Table` component while rendering the column headers, change the onClick so that it sends the `columnHeader` to `sortData` function

```js
{headerData.map((headerTable) => (
  <th onClick={() => sortData(headerTable)} id={"header-"+headerTable.toLowerCase()}>
     {headerTable} <img src={ordIcon} id="arrow-img"></img>
  </th>
))}
```

And finally in the `sortData` function,

```js
const sortData = (columnHeader) => {
    const {key, type} = columnMap[columnHeader];

    const sorted = [...newUserArr].sort((a, b) => {
        let sortValue = 0;

        if (type === 'date') {
            sortValue = new Date(a[key]) - new Date(b[key]);
        } else {
            sortValue = a[key].localeCompare(b[key]);
        }

        return order === 'dsc' ? -(sortValue) : sortValue;
    });

    setNewUserArr(sorted);

    if (order === '' || 'asc') {
        setOrder('dsc');
        setOrdIcon(arrowDown);
    } else {
        setOrder('asc');
        setOrdIcon(arrowUp);
    }    
};
```

We first find the key using which we need to sort `newUserArr`, we also need type here because for dates we cannot use `localeCompare`. Then we sort the array, if order is `dsc` then we reverse the sort.

EDIT -
For sort icons, we could keep track of the current sort state of each column and then use it in `Table` component

In `Home` component

```js
const [sortStatus, setSortStatus] = useState({});
```

And change `sortData` to

```js
const sortData = (columnHeader) => {
    const {key, type} = columnMap[columnHeader];

    const sorted = [...newUserArr].sort((a, b) => {
        let sortValue = 0;

        if (type === 'date') {
            sortValue = new Date(a[key]) - new Date(b[key]);
        } else {
            sortValue = a[key].localeCompare(b[key]);
        }

        return order === 'dsc' ? -(sortValue) : sortValue;
    });

    setNewUserArr(sorted);

    setSortStatus((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        [columnHeader]: order === 'dsc' ? 'asc' : 'dsc'
    }))
};
```

In `Table` component,

```js
const getSortIcon = (columnHeader) => {
   if (!sortStatus[columnHeader]) {
      return "↕︎";
   }
   
   return sortStatus[columnHeader] === 'dsc' ? "↓" : "↑"; 
};

{headerData.map((headerTable) => (
    <th onClick={sortData} id={"header-"+headerTable.toLowerCase()}>
    {headerTable}
    {getSortIcon(headerTable)}
    </th>
))}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you for your answer. Do you know if there is a way that i can make the icon of asc or dsc change only in the column that i click?

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check @Dênis

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, i tried it but now it stoped showing the icons